# checkout is not working in magento1.7

Tags: php, magento, checkout, authorize.net, magento-1.7

I have a multistore done in `Magento 1.7`. Checkout is not working in one store. Nothing is happening after clicking the continue button inside `Billing Information` block which calls the function `onclick="billing.save()"`. I checked with firebug all blocks are coming correctly. I think the problem is with the function `billing.save()`. Where I can find this function.

***EDIT***

I have checked my response in `transport.responseText` in `billing.save()` for one store I am getting response like this

```
{"goto_section":"shipping_method","update_section":{"name":"shipping-method","html":"<dl class=\"sp-methods\">\r\n<p>We are shipping daily until 12.19.2011 although most orders will arrive for the Holidays, we can not guarentee 12.25.2011 delivery (for orders placed after 12.14.2011). <span style=\"color:red;\">We begin shipping again in January - Order Honeybells Now!<\/span><\/p>\r\n            <dt>Flat Shipping<\/dt>\r\n        <dd>\r\n            <ul>\r\n                            <li>\r\n                                                                   <span class=\"no-display\"><input name=\"shipping_method\" type=\"radio\" value=\"flatship_flatship\" id=\"s_method_flatship_flatship\" checked=\"checked\" \/><\/span>\r\n                                                <label for=\"s_method_flatship_flatship\">Standard US                                                                        <span class=\"price\">$12.00<\/span>                                                <\/label>\r\n                                   <\/li>\r\n                        <\/ul>\r\n        <\/dd>\r\n    <\/dl>\r\n"},"allow_sections":["shipping"],"duplicateBillingInfo":"true"}
```

and for the store which is not working its coming like this

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
{"goto_section":"shipping_method","update_section":{"name":"shipping-method","html":"<dl class=\"sp-methods\">\r\n<p>We are shipping daily until 12.19.2011 although most orders will arrive for the Holidays, we can not guarentee 12.25.2011 delivery (for orders placed after 12.14.2011). <span style=\"color:red;\">We begin shipping again in January - Order Honeybells Now!<\/span><\/p>\r\n            <dt>Flat Shipping<\/dt>\r\n        <dd>\r\n            <ul>\r\n                            <li>\r\n                                                                   <span class=\"no-display\"><input name=\"shipping_method\" type=\"radio\" value=\"flatship_flatship\" id=\"s_method_flatship_flatship\" checked=\"checked\" \/><\/span>\r\n                                                <label for=\"s_method_flatship_flatship\">Standard US                                                                        <span class=\"price\">$43.80<\/span>                                                <\/label>\r\n                                   <\/li>\r\n                        <\/ul>\r\n        <\/dd>\r\n    <\/dl>\r\n"},"allow_sections":["shipping"],"duplicateBillingInfo":"true"}
```

I don't know from where this meta tag is coming and when I alert `response.update_section.name` in side  `setStepResponse: function(response){` its coming as undefined...

**EDIT 2**

Now meta tag problem has been solved.. They have added that meta tag inside index.php of their sub domain folder.
 **Now the problem is when I place order it displays**

> Gateway error: (TESTMODE) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.

Any one has any idea please help me. Its working fine in another store. I am using `Authorize.net` for payment and enabled `Test Mode`.

Comment: Magento, by default, doesn not provide this option (to display google-site-verification meta tag).

This tag is coming from theme customization or some extension. Do:

`grep -R "google-site-verification" app/`

and it will display where this tag is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function can be found in

```
skin/frontend/your_package/your_theme/js/optcheckout.js
```

or, if it's not in /your_package/your_theme/ and /your_package/default/, it's in /base/default/

In Magento 1.7 is should be in the line 302 of the file (if nothing was modified).

But I don't think the problem is there. Have you checked the response for saveBilling in Firebug/Developer Tools?

Comment: i have checked with response i am getting only `<meta name="google-site-verification" content="B0lGkVaiNyp6aVhDbPpUA-TDFuMYguBSa8e9fEujFF8" />
{"goto_section":"shipping"}` where i can find the function which returns the response

Comment: i think the div with class name `checkout-shipping-method-load is missing` i don't know where to add it

Comment: i don't have `col-right` class div. I read many thread which is asking to add a dummy div like that but i don't know where to add this

Answer (score 2):

I've had a very similar problem

I've found that on Magento 1.7.0.2 Onepage checkout when I click the continue button after filling in the Billing details the button disappears and nothing else happens.

What I've tried:
First of all debugging the JS gives me the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefined opcheckout.js:81
Checkout._disableEnableAll opcheckout.js:81
Checkout.setLoadWaiting opcheckout.js:94
Billing.save opcheckout.js:307
onclick
```

And the following error in Chrome

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:239
babyCS.getSelectedText chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:239
babyCS.saveSelection chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:209
babyCS.click
```

I also rolled back the server to an image taken just before our last order, even though we know this code works (as an order was placed using that code) when we run it now we get the same issue.

So we figured it might be due to a change in the config settings, rather than a code issue.
We changed the 'shipping method' config for Free Shipping (our only shipping option) from 'specified countries' to 'All allowed countries' and it fixed the issue... for about 5 minutes! We tested it from a couple of locations and it worked, so we switched the discounts back on and it all vanished again.

To get to this step I can see in Fiddler there's a call to

```
/checkout/onepage/progress/?toStep=billing
```

But when I click the Continue button to go to the next step it doesn't appear to call `/?toStep=shipping`

Answer (score 1):

I think the error explain it self ? have you contacted Authorize.net and checked your test account if its working ??

Answer (score 0):

I am gussing you're getting the problem in IE9? there's a know issue with the checkout which only affects certain IE versions. Can you try Chrome or FF and see if the issue is still there?

If this is indeed the same issue, this can be overcome by forcing IE into IE8mode

You can try adding this to your htaccess:

```
BrowserMatch MSIE best-standards-support
Header set X-UA-Compatible IE=8 env=best-standards-support
```

Comment: Do you have a link I could take a look at? I may be able to help :)

Comment: i am getting `response.update_section` as undefined inside the function  `setStepResponse: function(response){` in`optcheckout.js`

Comment: i don't have `col-right` class div. I read many thread which is asking to add a dummy div like that but i don't know where to add this

Comment: Did you remove the right hand column from your checkout page? The column which includes the progress etc. If so then the javascript is probably causing errors and stopping the page working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding EDIT 2:

I believe that the problem is with your account. You can check it by creating another test account under https://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/
You can access this account on https://test.authorize.net/
Try using test account in Magento and see if there are any problems with it.

Also, remember to use https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll gateway address for testing and https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll when setting Authorize.net to process real transactions.